# Triple DES encryption from javascript to Ruby or other language

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption

I am working with a third party service where they are using 3DES encryption using pkcs7 padding. Right now they have provided me the working version in javascript. Currently i face problem in converting the JS to Ruby

This is the working version of ruby

```
var Encrypt3DesAccentiveCode = function (input, sec) {
        var len = sec.length / 2;
        var key1 = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(sec.substr(0, len));
        var key2 = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(sec.substr(len, len));
        var key3 = key1;
        var iv = key2;
        input = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(input);
        var result = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt(input, key1, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7, iv: iv });
        result = CryptoJS.TripleDES.decrypt(result, key2, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding, iv: iv });
        result = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt(result, key3, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding, iv: iv });
        return (result.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
    }
```

Secret is A5240DB03E029CFAD369C312ACD4BD66
Data is TXRAZEZ8
Final encrypted value is NBHRwUjzOm761HnKA2FUEg==

I have tried the encryption in ruby initially like this

```
def encrypt(data, key)
  len = key.length / 2
  key1 = "A5240DB03E029CFA"
  iv = "D369C312ACD4BD66"

  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('DES3')
  cipher.encrypt # Must be called before anything else
  # Generate the key and initialization vector for the algorithm.
  # Alternatively, you can specify the initialization vector and cipher key
  # specifically using `cipher.iv = 'some iv'` and `cipher.key = 'some key'`
  cipher.key = key1
  cipher.iv = iv
  output = cipher.update(data) + cipher.final
  Base64.strict_encode64 output
end
```

I have also tried DES-EDE3-CBC but not able to acheive the required output. I have logged each line in JS to do it in ruby, But it is giving me WordArray and ruby is working differently.

Even if the conversion is in python script i can execute the file and get the output in ruby.

Comment: I think the first example is wrong...         var key2 = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(sec.substr(len, len));
 doesn't make sense, it should surely be         var key2 = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(sec.substr(len, len*2));

Comment: i.e. key1=0 -> half way, key2= half way -> end

Comment: Also, they don't implement tripple des per se, instead, you have some kind of tripple-trippel-des (that is, something that looks like tripple-des but instead of building on top of DES and its usual usual encrypt-decrypt-encrypt dance, they build it on top of tripple-des itself. Thus, what you have shown there is definitely NOT an implementation of standard trippel-des but some weird home-grown cipher.